# HttpClient como fazer uma requisição a cada 1 segundo

Tags: c#

Tem como eu fazer uma requisição via HttpClient a cada 1 segundo?

O servidor que eu mando as solicitações broqueia a requisição se for uma atras da outra com uma resposta: "RequestBlocked"

O que eu queria era o seguinte: eu mandava fazer 2 solicitações,
entretanto ele faria a primeira requisição e retornaria seu valor, 1 segundo depois ele faria a segunda requisição e assim por diante, tem como fazer algo assim?

Código

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var result = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost/api/request.php");
    return result.StatusCode.ToString();
}
```

Comment: em que está fazendo seu projeto jovem, windows forms ? dê mais detalhes por favor. Coloque também o código que já tens pronto. A pergunta do jeito que está certamente será fechada por ser ampla de mais, ou não ser clara o suficiente. Aproveite e faça  o tour do site: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Oi, eu uso winform,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para isso você pode usar um controle `Timer`, que pode ser arrastado diretamente da toolbox.

Defina a propriedade `Interval` para 1000 (milisegundos) = 1 segundo, e manipule o evento `Tick`, colocando a requisição dentro dele.

Ao iniciar o form, habilita o timer.

Segue código exemplo:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Request();

        int count = results.Count;
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }

    Queue<string> results = new Queue<string>();
    private async void Request()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var result = await client.GetAsync("http://google.com");
             results.Enqueue(result.StatusCode.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Resultado:

[image: Resultado código]

Comment: Já que ele vai usar o `GetAsync` de qualquer jeito, não é mais simples usar `await Task.Delay(1000)` ao invés de um `Timer` só pra isso?

Comment: @VítorMartins se puder, coloque uma resposta de como ficaria o código, me interesso também, obrigado

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta :)

Answer (score 0):

Se você precisar tratar uma fila, veja a [resposta do Rovann](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/225610/45294).

Se você quiser esperar todas as Requests completarem e processar todas de uma vez, é mais simples da forma abaixo. Eu, pessoalmente, acho timers bastante imprevisíveis.

```
public static async Task<IDictionary<string, string>> Requests(params string[] urls)
{
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        foreach(string url in urls)
        {
            var result = await client.GetAsync(url);                
            dictionary.Add(url, result.StatusCode.ToString());

            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }

    return dictionary;
}
```

[Veja funcionando.](http://rextester.com/EQLX65473)